# COUNTROWS in Table where value is less than N POWER BI Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with Orders and a table with Order Status (relationship 1:many on Order Status), I'm trying to filter or Count the rows in the Order Status table less than or equal to the minimum value in the Orders table, for example the minimum value here would be 2, so I want to get only the rows "Order Created" and "Shipped" in the Order Status table.

I have tried creating the measure below with no luck:

```
Status = 
var minvalue = min('Orders'[Order Status #])

RETURN = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Order Status'), 
    'Order Status #' <= minvalue
)
```

[Tables and Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqasJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table by filtering the **status table** based on the value on **order table** with `filter` function as following , accept the answer if helping :)

```
Table = FILTER('Status','Status'[Order status #]<=MIN(Orders[order status #]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That would work if I only have one Order but I have multiple orders in the Order table, any thoughts on how can I modify your formula to make it work for multiple orders, based on an order that I select in a slicer?

Comment: Definitely it can be solved, but I have no idea on your actual issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to show/hide row from **Status** table, you can create this below **Measure** as flag-

```
show_hide_flag = 
var min_order_status = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN(Orders[Order Status #]),
    ALL(Orders)
)

RETURN 
IF(
    MIN('Status'[Order Status #]) <= min_order_status,
    1,
    0
)
```

Here is row wise value for the above **Measure**-

[image]

Now you can apply filter using the new **flag** measure and the output will be as below-

[image]

**But**, if you only wants the count of rows from table **Status**, you can create a **Measure** as below-

```
count_ = 
var min_order_status = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN(Orders[Order Status #]),
    ALL(Orders)
)

RETURN 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL('Status'),
        'Status'[Order Status #] <= min_order_status
    )
)
```

And here is the output-

[image]